# order by with placeholders in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

What's the proper way to generate an order by like `ORDER BY myfunction(col, ?, ?) DESC` with bind values in `DBIx::Class`?

Currently I use literal SQL for this, but that's not optimal for several reasons.

```
$rs->search(undef, { order_by => \"myfunction(col, $v1, $v2) DESC" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage to get `DBIx::Class` to generate the correct `ORDER BY`. Here is the code:

```
$rs->search(undef, {
    order_by => \[
        'myfunction(mycol, ?, ?) DESC', map [dummy => $_], $v1, $v2
    ]
});
```

Comment: BTW, this is documented in [Literal SQL with placeholders and bind values (subqueries)](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/SQL-Abstract-1.73/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Literal_SQL_with_placeholders_and_bind_values_%28subqueries%29) in SQL::Abstract

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
$rs->search(
    undef,
    {
        '+columns' => [{
            'res' => {
                'func' => ['me.col', \['?' => $val1], \['?' => $val2]],
                '-as'  => 'res',
            },
        }],
        'order_by' => {'-desc' => 'res'},
    }
);
```

will generate (for MySQL & `($val1, $val2) = qw(val1 val2)`):

```
SELECT `me`.`id`, ..., FUNC( `me`.`col`, ?, ? ) AS `res`
    FROM `table` `me`
    ORDER BY `res` DESC:
'val1',
'val2'
```

Comment: It's a fine solution, +1. I'll stick with mine because this one populates an additional column in the Row object (i.e. the result of `$row->get_columns` will contain 'res'), and that would break some code.

Comment: As workaround you can mark this column (e.g. `-res`) and remove it in extended `DBIx::Class::Row::inflate_result()` method.